# how to send dynamic props in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

```
<Route exact path="/product/:id" element={<ProductPage />} prod_id={this.id}/>
```

Here i have a route what my intension is to get the the id of the path in my component so that i can fire the function and get the details of the product
obviously `prod_id={this.id}` is not working for me and also supposed to not work writing this is intention just to show what i am thinking

once i get this id in my component i can fire this function

```
export const getSingle=(id) => async(dispatch)=>{
    try {
        dispatch({type:SINGLE_PRODUCT_REQUEST})
        const {data} = await axios.get(`/api/v1/products/detail:${id}`)
        dispatch({
            type:SINGLE_PRODUCT_SUCCESS,
            payload:data,
        })
    } catch (error) {
        
        dispatch({
            type:SINGLE_PRODUCT_FAIL,
            payload:error.response.data.message,
        })
    }

}
```

to get the product detail and fill the required field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant pass props to Route and access them in target component. This is not how things in React work.

If you want to access params from URL, you can use hooks - useParams()

```
    export const getSingle= () => async(dispatch)=>{
    try {
        dispatch({type:SINGLE_PRODUCT_REQUEST})
        const params: { id: string } = useParams();
        const {data} = await axios.get(`/api/v1/products/detail:${params.id}`)
        dispatch({
            type:SINGLE_PRODUCT_SUCCESS,
            payload:data,
        })
    } catch (error) {
        
        dispatch({
            type:SINGLE_PRODUCT_FAIL,
            payload:error.response.data.message,
        })
    }

}
```

For non functional component, you have to access params from props

```
  class Example extends Component {
    render() {
        const { id } = this.props.match.params;
        return (
            <div>ID : { id }</div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can get `id` from `useParams()` hook.

Route code

```
<Route exact path="/product/:id" element={<ProductPage />} />
```

in react component, import `useParams` hook from `react-router-dom`
and get id using

```
let { id } = useParams();
```